# Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unsupported driver [] - illuminate database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have setup illuminate database package on my php mvc project. when i try to connect database, i got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unsupported driver [] in C:\laragon\www\mvctest1\vendor\illuminate\database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php:286
```

my database class config

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

class Database
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $db = new Capsule;
        $db->addConnection([
            'driver' => getenv('DB_DRIVER'),
            'host' => getenv('HOST'),
            'database' => getenv('DB_NAME'),
            'username' => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => ''
        ]);

        // Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
        $db->setAsGlobal();

        // Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
        $db->bootEloquent();
    }
}
```

Bootstrap init file config

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Start session if not already started
 */
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

// load environment variables
require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/config/_env.php';

//instantiate database class
new \App\Classes\Database();

require_once __DIR__ . '/../app/routing/routes.php';

new \App\Routing\RouteDispatcher($router);
```

and my env file config

```
APP_URL=http://mvctest1.test/
APP_ENV=local
APP_NAME="mvc test 1"

#database
DB_DRIVER='mysql'
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_NAME=store
DB_USERNAME=store
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

Can someone please help me to fix this error...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am using version 9.51.0 and following the documentation and still having this issue. Reverting back to version 8.4 and my issue is fine.